# When machine-wide tracing is enabled, where does ODBC store logs for NETWORKSERVICE?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, odbc

When I enable machine-wide tracing in odbcad32.exe, it says:

> A log file will be created if none exists for every user identity under which a process using odbc is running.

However, it doesn't say where they'll be created. Presumably for normal users they'll be under `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, since that's the default path, but what about system users like `NETWORKSERVICE`, which the MS Distributed Transaction Services (`msdtc.exe`)?

It's using ODBC - I have a debugger attached to it and I can see it calling into the DTC XA co-ordinator, where it makes calls to `SQLDriverConnect`, etc. But I don't see any trace.

Where should I be looking?

I'm using Win2k8 R2 SP1.

Comment: Try checking for the path under the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ODBC\ODBC.ini\ODBC

Comment: @Debra That's just the same path that's configured in `odbcad32.exe`. The message implies that the path for multi-user tracing creates a file per user though, so it can't be a single path unless it has some kind of wildcard/placeholder, or adds a per user prefix/suffix. Right? Or is the message misleading, with all users really logged into one file? (The log file path given in `odbcad32.exe` is created for me, but remains empty if I enable multi-user tracing).

Comment: I haven't verified this but there are articles on the progress.com site (e.g. http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000001993 ) that suggest checking C:\Windows and %TEMP% .